# Django: one variable has different values in template

Tags: html, django, url

Like the title says, I'm passing a variable to a django template called 'old_link' as such:

```
{% if type_disp == 'charts' %}<li class="active">{% endif %}<a href="{% url 'matching:analytics' action=action type_disp='charts'  %}?{{old_link}}" class="text-primary"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-bolt"></i>Charts</a></li>
{% if type_disp == 'tables' %}<li class="active">{% endif %}<a href="{% url 'matching:analytics' action=action type_disp='tables'  %}?{{old_link}}" class="text-primary"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-calendar"></i>Table</a></li>
```

The 'old_link' variable is supposed to get added to the end of the url, but it keeps giving me the wrong link. To test it I also posted the variable in another part of the template to see what it returns. You can see the correct value above the 'number of companies' section in the picture below. The value where it's posted in the sheet and the value where it's posted in the url are completely different and I'm not sure why.

In the picture below you can see the url portion where the variable is supposed to be applied, it shows 'http://127.0.0.1...' instead of the 'year_min...' value that it should.

[image]
Here's the full template code:

```
   <div class="item col-md-8 col-xs-12">

    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <h4 class="text-headline margin-none">{{company_amount}}</h4>
                    <p class="text-light">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle-o text-success fa-fw"></i> Total Funding
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <h4 class="text-headline margin-none">{{old_link}}</h4>
                    <p class="text-light">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle-o text-danger fa-fw"></i> Number of
                        Companies
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


                <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">{{title}}</h4>
                </div>

                {% if type_disp == 'charts' %}
                    {% with form=entity_choice_form %}
                        {% include 'common/form-alert.html' %}
                    {% endwith %}
                    <div class="panel-body">
                    {% if action == 'industry-compare' %}
                        <div id="industry-compare"></div>
                    {% elif action == 'insurtech-total' %}
                        <div id="insurtech-total"></div>
                    {% elif action == 'industry-concentration' %}
                        <div id="industry-concentration"></div>
                    {% elif action == 'new-entrants' %}
                        <div id="new-entrants"></div>
                    {% endif %}
            {% elif type_disp == 'tables' %}
                    <div class="panel-body">


                    {% render_table Table_Values %}    

               {% endif %}
                </div>
           </div>
        </div>
<div class="col-md-2">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">  

            {% if type_disp == 'charts' %}<li class="active">{% endif %}<a href="{% url 'matching:analytics' action=action type_disp='charts'  %}?{{old_link}}" class="text-primary"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-bolt"></i>Charts</a></li>
            {% if type_disp == 'tables' %}<li class="active">{% endif %}<a href="{% url 'matching:analytics' action=action type_disp='tables'  %}?{{old_link}}" class="text-primary"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-calendar"></i>Table</a></li>


    </ul>
</div>
```

The first time the variable is called is in 'h4' and then it's again called in the nav pills. Here's how I pass the variable in my views:

```
'old_link':referer1,
```

I've already validated that 'refer1' has the value I want. How do I ensure that the variable is the same in both places and why is it different in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
{% if type_disp == 'charts' %}<li class="active">{% endif %}<a href="{% url 'matching:analytics' action=action type_disp='charts'  %}?old_link={{old_link}}" class="text-primary"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-bolt"></i>Charts</a></li>
```

You have to put key=value in url (?old_link={{old_link}})

Comment: I tried that and it's still giving me different values.